# Why won't my 3rd party DLLs copy to the output folder when I attempt to debug in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2015

In our solution, we have two projects setup. One is the server project which starts the application, and is set as the Startup Project. The other is a library project that depends on two JNBridge DLLs.

JNBridge states that the DLLs must be in output directory in order to work. So we've set the properties of the DLLs as Copy Always.

When I do a build, I see that the JNBridge DLLs are copied to the output directory, as expected.

[image]

However, when I click on Start Debugging (F5) in VS2015, I see that the DLLs are missing. I see that those DLLs are removed from the output folder after clicking on Start Debugging.

Is there something wrong with the solution setup?

I have the following project setup in my solution:

```
Solution
  Server
    bin\Debug
    Server.cs
  Subsystem
    bin\Debug
    jnbauth_x86.dll
    JNBSharedMem_x86.dll
    Subsystem.cs
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just want to copy the DLL file to the output directory, change Build Action to None.

Comment: Can you please tell me where this option is located in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Look at the image in your post.